# How do I only show my Facebook group in android app using API Requests?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I want to show only my `Facebook groups` in my `android apps`.

I tried to do this using `API Requests`

> Can anyone post any thread or sample example/code ?
>
> Any better way to implement my task?

thanks I'm new in android development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cna make a graph API request

You can make these requests using the Android SDK, as shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) .

You will receive JSON as the return value, and you can use this however you see fit in your Android application.

Then you can access the groups like this with a graph API

```
{
 "id": "195466193802264",
 "version": 1,
 "owner": {
    "name": "Ravi Grover",
    "id": "202875"
   },
 "name": "Facebook Developers",
 "description": "Description.",
 "venue": {
    "street": ""
 },
 "privacy": "OPEN",
 "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yI/r/0pjqWL1NfkE.png",
 "updated_time": "2011-03-12T02:43:05+0000",
 "email": "195466193802264\u0040groups.facebook.com" 
}
```

[Starting with Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/)

[API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: thanks what about `Facebook SDK` ? is it something different from API ? sorry m newbie in android

Comment: The android SDK can make various requests to the API of FB. These are the graph API, FQL and the REST API. You can do this by running the SDK's methods. They are given in the link at the top of my Answer. Once you request the Graph API you'll get a JSON response. Convert that to a JAVA array and have fun with the data