# How to show the posts in a facebook group on an android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, development-environment

I've recently made an app for my club, and thats looking pretty smooth. But I'm missing one thing, and thats the function to view the statuses and events of the facebook group on my android app. Do you have any good idea for doing something like that? Thanks! :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Answer:

[How do I only show my Facebook group in android app using API Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049966/how-do-i-only-show-my-facebook-group-in-android-app-using-api-requests)

You can make a graph API request ;)